# JQuery Pagination Issues

Tags: jquery, wordpress, plugins, pagination

Ok so I am trying to make a system that has three parts. A menu, a content area, and a pagination area. Each of these areas, excluding menu, is loaded via a .load call from jquery at run time. I am doing this as a wordpress plugin by the way.

For instance at load, I load the posts.php via .load into the .content class and the page.php via .load into the .pagination class. This is all done with default settings, ie I send default settings via post method of load. The menu code is there from the start.

The issue is with pagination. I would like it so when you click the next page it loads the next content and move the page up on the pagination system, all with out loading the whole page again in wordpress. I figured jquery would work here but the issue is that if I call pagination as a jquery call, when a user clicks the next page, the detection would have to be nested in the first pagination call, right? Which because a massive loop.

So the issue is how to make a pagination system that will call the next content and load it into the content area and move the page up in its own system, without having to load the whole page again due to it being a plugin in wordpress.

Any help?

**edit:**
I want to point out that I am newer to jQuery.

Comment: I think my issue is how to make nested calls. That is I loaded a file via .load and the returned html is now a new dom object, and so to call an element in it, from what I know, you have to put it under the .load function that loaded the html.

Answer (score 1):

Assuming your `load()` returns data that looks something like this:

```
<ul>
    <li>item1</li>
    <li>item2</li>
</ul>
<div id='pagination'> 
    1 
    <a href='/path/to/this/page?page=2'>2</a>
    <a href='/path/to/this/page?page=3'>3</a>
</div>
```

You could modify all of the `<a>` tags after loading them into a particular div, like so:

```
$('#mymenu').load('/path/to/this/page?page=1', function(){
    setAjaxLinks();
});
```

And have a function `setAjaxLinks` defined like this:

```
$('#mymenu').find('a').click(function(event){
    event.preventDefault();
    $('#mymenu').load($(this).attr('href'), function(){
        setAjaxLinks();
    });
    return false;
});
```

The key point of the `setAjaxLinks` function is that it sets a function for what to do when a link is clicked.  Which is:

1. Send an AJAX request for the next page and load it into the appropriate location on the page.
2. Find the paging links in the response, and replace their `click` events with what we'd like the paging links to do, which is...

   A. Send an AJAX request.. and

   B. Find the paging links in the response, and replace their `click` events with....

So we end up with a recursive `setAjaxLinks` call.

Comment: Interesting but I really didn't have a setup for the pagination part. I had one at a time that sent back html that was more like <a href="#" id="c_page" name="$current">$current</a> for each page. I also had a pagination system that was loaded on the first php page and had no jquery for it.

The idea with the first one was to call $("c_page").click and get its name value. and send that info back through jquery to reload the php for content and pagination, but I couldn't get that to work.

Comment: As for your setAjaxLinks function, I am lost on how that would work.